# DateTimeOffset format and get the same output as moment.js

Tags: c#, momentjs

I am able to format date in moment.js with this pattern:

```
MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a
```

And it will return:

```
January 1st 0001, 12:00:24 am
```

However, doing the same with C# DateTimeOffset will return:

```
date.ToString("MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a")

> January Do YYYY, 12:00:00 a
```

I am wondering how do I achieve the same output?

Comment: Look at the docs for date formatting in .NET. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Answer (score 1):

You can install the [Humanizer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Humanizer) nuget package and do:

```
date.ToString($"MMMM \"{date.Day.Ordinalize()}\" yyyy, h:mm:ss tt")
```

Answer (score 1):

This is without Humanizer, You can create the same function for `DateTimeOffset`, it will work the same

```
    public static string ToDisplayDate(DateTime date)
    {
        int day = date.Day;
        string dayStringOrdinal = day +
            ((day % 10 == 1 && day != 11) ? "st"
            : (day % 10 == 2 && day != 12) ? "nd"
            : (day % 10 == 3 && day != 13) ? "rd" : "th");

        return date.ToString("MMMM DAY, h:mm:ss tt").Replace("DAY", dayStringOrdinal);
    }
```

output :

```
August 13th, 08:35:58 AM
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   date.ToString("MMMM dd")+  GetSuffix(date.Day) + date.ToString(" yyyy, h:mm:ss a")

            string GetSuffix(int day){

            return (day % 10 == 1 && day != 11) ? "st"
            : (day % 10 == 2 && day != 12) ? "nd"
            : (day % 10 == 3 && day != 13) ? "rd"
            : "th";
             }
```